# First relative path tilde (~) not being recognized?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm taking some MVC.net training, and noticed something weird about the tilde.

I have a list of links to scripts that look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

But when I run the application on my machine, the jquery wasn't working. Checking the source code, I notice that the first tilde wasn't being converted as it should:

(source code:)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

It can be pretty easily fixed by just adding a link to nothing at the top of the list:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/nothing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

But I was wondering if any of you have seen anything like this, or had an explanation as to what is going on?

Comment: Never seen anything like that before. Only thing I can think of is maybe there's some invalid markup or code on the view which is funking up the rendering, but not bad enough to cause an exception. I'd suggest removing the rest of the stuff on the page a little at a time and see if it clears up.

Comment: maybe don't reference the minified version

Comment: Just a followup in that I got that most frustrating of solutions, "It just started working."  Only advice I can give is "have you tried turning it off and on again?" Since the next day, I arrived at the office, started VS 2013, loaded the same project and that issue was gone.

Comment: Nice, it's the old "Microsoft solution".

Comment: I had this and it was caused by an extra " in an html element, such as <i class="jjj" ">.